# Powershell - store package loss and time in separate variables

Tags: powershell, connection, ping

[image]

How can I store the average round trip time and the package loss in separate variables? I do not want to store the whole ping result. The output should just be:

In this case I want the output to be:

```
0% loss, 14 ms
```

Is this possible?
THANKS!!

Comment: It is indeed possible, and the answer shows you how. If the solution provided there doesn't work (for you), please provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: the usual recommendation applies:

- It's better to use a native PowerShell solutions, such as [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection), which provides *objects* as output, whose *properties* you can access, which is both conceptually clearer and more robust than parsing what is invariably *text* output from *external programs*.

---

You can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with its `-Regex` option:

```bash
$lossPercent, $avgPingTime = 
  switch -regex (ping 8.8.8.8) {
    '(\d+)%' { [int] $Matches.1  }
    'Average = (\d+)ms' { [int] $Matches.1  }
  }

"$lossPercent% loss, $avgPingTime ms"
```

Note: `$avgPingTime` will be `$null` if no ping attempt succeeded.
It looks like `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 1` returning `$true` indicates this condition too.